# hazelcast Map Loading while initial startup

Tags: hazelcast

I am working on hazelcast to set up a distributed Cache.
I want to populate the cache Map once while startup.
I read through the MapLoader and MapStore.Suggest me the best way to do it.
And i want to know how it actually works.
Thanks.

Comment: still pending or figured it out?